# React Native - Reinstall expo after expo eject

Tags: react-native, expo

I was having issues using the `react-native-image-picker` library. So, I tried to link the RCTCameraRoll adding it to the Xcode libraries. However, to open my project using Xcode I had to run `expo eject`.

Now, how can I run my project? When run the command: `expo start` it returns:

```
Property 'expo' in app.json is not an object. Please make sure app.json includes a managed Expo app config like this: {"expo":{"name":"My app","slug":"my-app","sdkVersion":"..."}}
No Expo configuration found. Are you sure this is a project directory?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `expo`, you can use **ImagePicker**, but you don't have to make `Expo` a **stand-alone app**.

You can run `expo install expo-image-picker`

Usage

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { Button, Image, View } from 'react-native';
import * as ImagePicker from 'expo-image-picker';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import * as Permissions from 'expo-permissions';

export default class ImagePickerExample extends React.Component {
  state = {
    image: null,
  };

  render() {
    let { image } = this.state;

    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Button
          title="Pick an image from camera roll"
          onPress={this._pickImage}
        />
        {image &&
          <Image source={{ uri: image }} style={{ width: 200, height: 200 }} />}
      </View>
    );
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getPermissionAsync();
  }

  getPermissionAsync = async () => {
    if (Constants.platform.ios) {
      const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA_ROLL);
      if (status !== 'granted') {
        alert('Sorry, we need camera roll permissions to make this work!');
      }
    }
  }

  _pickImage = async () => {
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
      allowsEditing: true,
      aspect: [4, 3],
    });

    console.log(result);

    if (!result.cancelled) {
      this.setState({ image: result.uri });
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: I receive the warning: "[Unhandled promise rejection: Error: Missing camera roll permission.]" using iOS simulator